# How to show a particular recurrence $x_{n+1} = {4\over 3}x_n - x_n^2$ is bounded?

Tags: calculus, limits, recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds

Given a sequence:
$$
x_{n+1} = {4\over 3}x_n - x_n^2
$$
And initial conditions:
$$
x_1 = {1\over 6}
$$
I want to find $\lim x_n$ as $n\to\infty$. The approach i want to use is prove $x_n$ is bounded and monotone, hence convergent and then find its fixed points one of which is going to be the limit.

I have difficulties showing $x_n$ is bounded. If I make an assumption that it's bounded then for $L = \lim x_n$:
$$
3L^2 - L = 0 \iff L = 0\ \text{or}\ L = {1\over 3}
$$

Which in case $L\ne 0$ matches the answer. Could someone please assist me on showing the bounds for $x_n$? I would also like to know whether the rest reasoning is fine. Thank you.

Comment: There is at least a mistake in what you wrote. $x_{n+1} > x_n \iff -x_{n+1} > -x_n$ is wrong. Inequality has to be reverted when multiplied by a negative number.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net you're right, thanks for pointing out. I've updated the post.

Comment: But then your following equivalences are wrong.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net oh, you are right once again. In such case i'm not sure how to show the sequence is monotone :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's define $$e_n={1\over 3}-x_n$$then by substituting we obtain $$e_{n+1}={2\over 3}e_n+e_n^2=e_n\left({2\over 3}+e_n\right)$$with $e_1={1\over 6}$. Also note that if $e_n>0$ then $e_{n+1}>0$ therefore since $e_1>0$ we have $e_n>0$. Also if $e_n\le {1\over 6}$ we obtain $$e_{n+1}=e_n\left({2\over 3}+e_n\right)\le {5\over 6}e_n$$ finally $$0<e_{n+1}\le  {5\over 6}e_n$$which means that $e_n\to 0$ and $x_n\to {1\over 3}$ therefore $x_n$ is bounded.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you came up with such substitution? For me it looks like a lucky guess, i would like to grasp the technique

Comment: Sure! Since after finding $L=0$ and $L={1\over 3}$ we guessed that $x_n$ should converge ${1\over 3}$ then we are able to define the distance of $x_n$ to its final limit as $e_n=x_n-{1\over 3}$ or $e_n={1\over 3}-x_n$, not much different which one to choose and prove that the distance converges to $0$. A proof on convergence to $0$ is rather simpler than proving the convergence to any other point ---at least for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find explicit pattern and prove that it is bounded

Comment: Do you know what the explicit pattern is? maybe you can share it in your answer

Comment: Are you sure closed form exists?